# PHP - How to pass GET values through header?

Tags: php, get

I'm trying to pass the `$id` value through the `header()` function, but it seems to not work. because I can't get the value in the page redirecting to.

Here is the code snippet I'm working on:

```
$url = BASE_URL . 'send.php?id=' . $id;
header("Location: $url");
exit();
```

But when I try to get this value in the other file, doing `$id = $_GET['id']` I get a PHP Notice:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in (MY_FILE_PATH) on line 5
```

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: do you get redirect to the correct link? so does the Location: $url send you to: example.com/send.php?id=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to use [session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
header('Location: $url');
```

and next page like:

```
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```